# Codeigniter, when no parameters are provided?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Could someone tell what to do when you have a method like this:

```
class Start extends CI_Controller
{
    function foo($name)
    {
        //do something... 

    }
}
```

and the user of the website don't pass any parameters, e.g. when typing this in the address bar: website/controller/foo/(no $name parameter).

I want to show a different view when this happens, but i don't how to check for this.

PS. I know you  can use $this->uri->segment(); instead of parameters, but i would prefer not to.

Thanks

Comment: The user won't rendere the "foo($name)" method. If you have a simple "foo()" method you can map it to go yours.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the default value of `$name` to `NULL` and check whether it's set:

```
function foo($name = NULL)
{
    if(isset($name))
    {
        // Do something with $name
    }
    else
    {
        // $name not set
    }

}
```

Comment: +1 love what you've done with the `null`, really speaks to "Christmas"

Comment: @Xeoncross: I must've missed something :( Care to elaborate?

Comment: Must say, I'm a bit lost on the Christmas reference as well.